# Multithreading best method in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I am new in ASP, so it may be a basic question.

I need to write a site thatdo the following flow:

- user submit a request
- the site says: Thank you, you will be notified to e-mail when I'll finish.
- user ends session
- site do all the long proccess it have to
- site send an e-mail

Is it possible to continue the proccess after user ends the main session?

I read a bit, and I see that async pages won't do, so to use simple threading?

What is the best way to implement the flow?

Thanks,
Sara

Comment: If possible I would create a windows service with does the actual processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use simple threading:

```
protected void BtnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StatusLabel.Text = "Thank you, you will be notified to e-mail when I'll finish";
    new Thread(() => 
    {
        // some processing ... 
    }).Start();
}
```

The problem with this approach is that IIS could recycle your ASP.NET application under some conditions. For example after a period of inactivity (no user requests), or if a memory threshold is hit, ... This will result in aborting the execution of the long running operation.

For this reason it is better to implement such long running operations in separate services, such as a Windows Service. So you could for example [host a WCF Service inside a Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx). This service will do all the long processing and sending of email. Then from within the ASP.NET application you could simply invoke the corresponding method of this WCF service.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go the route of trying to run this in the web site code but rather build a separate windows service that runs on the box and processes these requests. Save a flag somewhere (database?) when the user makes his/her request and then pick it up from the service and process it there. The service can then email the person when it has completed the task. If you really want to do the bulk of the work in the web site, you can create a web service and call that from your windows service.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you call into a back-end service for your deferred processing.  You might create a WCF service that you can call on an MsmqBinding.  Such a service is a queued service and allows you to do exactly what you're asking for.  It abstracts the complexities of MSMQ and makes it real easy to implement the service.  For hosting your service, if you can use AppFabric that's great; otherwise host your service in IIS Windows Activation Service if you can.  If none of those are available to you, you can create your own Windows Service to host the WCF service that you write - it's just a bit more complicated to self-host that way.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible due to the IIS threading model.

You'll need to create another program that spins in the background processing these sorts of requests.  There's various frameworks that do this sort of thing though.  Maybe check out Quartz.NET?

http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what you are trying to do ... where the persisted data sits ... etc.

I would not use multiple threads in IIS, as other have also suggested. Too much risk, esp. on a long running process. What you will end up with is "fire and forget". The exact mechanism? There are many choices:

1. Call another service (suggested already)
2. Use a queueing system, like MSMQ
3. If the work can be done in SQL Server, queue with SQL Server Service Broker (SSSB)

The actual contact mechanism (sending email) will be handled by the back end "process" and not the service.